# About '' get injured '' and '' be injured ''

Tags: passive-voice

How do you use '' get p.p.''and"be p. p. "differently? For example" get injured "and" be injured". Is there any difference between them?

Comment: You "get injured" at a certain time.  Then you "are injured" from that time until you are finally healed.

Comment: Among other uses, _get_ is the inchoative (change-of-state) verb of _be_. So any predicate adjective that represents a changeable state can be expressed with _get_ to refer to the beginning of the state (_He got tired_) or with _be_ to refer to the state itself (_He was tired_). If the predicate is formed from a p.p, like _arrested_, it could be interpreted as a passive of a transitive verb (_He was arrested by the police_). [_Get_ is also possible with passives (_He got arrested by the police_)](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+get+passive+inchoative).

Comment: What is "p.p."?

Answer (score 0):

In AmE, "get injured" is applied more to emergent, present situations:

*"Turn off the engine before you stick your hand in there, or you'll* ***get injured*** *."*

"Be injured", is more often used in a hypothetical, future sense:

*"You may* ***be injured*** *in the line of duty."*

This is not a rule - but, a common nuance.